# Laravel 5 - can't get parameters from redirect::route

Tags: laravel, redirect, parameters, routes, laravel-5

I have this code in a controller:

```
$id = 1;
$name = 'Phil';
return Redirect::route('myroute')->with('id',$id)->with('name',$name);
```

Then in my routes file I have the following:

```
Route::get('test/{id}/{name}',array('as' => 'myroute', 'uses' => 'MyController@myFunction'));
```

And finally the function in MyController:

```
 public myFunction($id,$name) {
        return $name;
 }
```

Instead of getting the content of the variable name printed 'Phil', I get the string '{name}'.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the route parameters as the second argument to route():

```
return Redirect::route('myroute', ['id' => $id, 'name' => $name]);
```

`->with()` puts the items in the Input for the next request, rather than being route parameters.